# Easier way to solve this partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

> Let $u=x+ct, v=x-ct$ and $z=\log u +\sin v^2$ then $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial t^2}-c^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}=0$.

Is there any way to see $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial t^2}-c^2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}=0$, other than direct computation?

Comment: Yes. Considering the general solution for this PDE: $z(t,x)=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$ Then, with $f(w)=\sin w^2$ and $g(w)=\log w$ you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Consider it as

$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-c\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+c\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)z = 0
$$

and after that applying the boundary conditions.

Comment: How do you know the left hand side term will equal to $0$?

Comment: If you need to solve a partial derivative you should know how it is.